# File size limits when logging objects to JSON file via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, analytics

I just finished writing an analytics plugin for a javascript app that I built.  The plugin is currently logging each user session as an object to a JSON file, via an AJAX call to this PHP code.

```
$log_url = '../../log.json';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($log_url),TRUE);
$session = json_decode($_POST['session']);
array_push($json, $session);
$encoded_json = 
json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$json_string = str_replace('\\', '', $encoded_json);
file_put_contents($log_url, $json_string);
```

If I am continuously logging to this file (about 30 entries a day), will I eventually reach a point where this file is too big and can't be quickly "json_decoded" by my script?  Is this a sustainable model or should I look towards other solution like database logging?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you decode it each time then? Why not just append the file with "json styled text" you manually create? Or don't use json, just a plain text file with columns that can be parsed?  There are many different solutions but since we don't know much about the json it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing Logs in File are very fast and efficient. But Storing Logs in database has its own advantage such as proper readability and you can even remotely access the logs. Store as much as you want and later on you can easily categories your data. A time will come when your log file will become too heavy and may cause lot of issues but database can never cause such issue.